# Host TCP Chat Server in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, tcp, chat

Im looking at [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33396-basic-clientserver-chat-application-in-c#/) basic chat server/client tutorial using TcpClient in .NET. Now I would like this put the chat server online on my web hosting provider. Is that possible? Can I host this server in IIS somehow? I could probably just start it in Application_Start but I dont think Im allowed to open a connection on any port just like that. What options do I have? I have made a chat app using WCF and net.tcp before but my hosting provider has not activated net.tcp on their IIS-server. So now Im looking at using a TcpClient instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd avoid attempting to use TCP in shared hosting scenarios. Why not use a HTTP WCF service instead? Most hosts lock down most ports except standard 80/443 and a few others. I can't see that they would allow you to open an arbitrary tcp port from their server, it could be a big security risk.

Answer (score 0):

I would not host a chat in IIS since you are limit to the application pool lifetime. Look after a hosting company that provides virtual servers instead.